# What does the C++ standard library guarantee to avoid data races?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, std

Reading [C++11 FAQ -- Threads](https://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-threads) there's this paragraph which I don't understand:

> Consequently, C++11 provides some rules/guarantees for the programmer to avoid data races:
>
> - A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly access objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's arguments, including this.
> - A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function's nonconst arguments, including this.
> - C++ standard library implementations are required to avoid data races when different elements in the same sequence are modified concurrently.

I know what a data race is, and multithreading generally, but I don't understand what these sentences are saying.

Could you explain them more clearly? Perhaps with an example? What is or isn't it safe for me (i.e. an application programmer) to do in a multi-threaded context?

Had I not read these, I would have guessed that it's not safe to have multiple threads calling a non-const method of an object of any type, but I suppose this is saying something in addition to that?

Comment: Those don't say anything about what is or isn't safe for you, a developer, to do.  It's making statements about what *the standard library* will and will not do.  This is really two questions - first what is the meaning of those three statements, and second what can you as a developer do to keep your application threadsafe.  For the latter, see [How to make an application thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5125241/327083)

Comment: re (3) does `std::vector<bool>` break this ? Found it _"... __Does not__ guarantee that different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: This is about the internals, always read the user documentation for code you use. Code is only threadsafe when it specifically states that it is and even then you have to use it correctly (e.g. std::unique_ptr, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482580/is-unique-ptr-thread-safe/11485874)

Comment: @J... If the library provides rules/guarantees, isn't that in order to make it safe for me to perform certain operations -- if so, what? And conversely perhaps to warn me that it's unsafe to invoke some operation for which the library doesn't make a guarantee? Anyway my primary question is, "what are these statements saying?".

Comment: @ChrisW No, it's a bit like meeting a new coworker on their first day.  You introduce each other and they make you a promise that they will never fold up a ladder and walk away with it while you're up and working on it.  At least not unless you do something dumb like chain their lunchbox to it without telling them.  It doesn't really tell you much about what is safe for **you** to do - it's just a single and very basic guarantee that **they** won't do anything catastrophically stupid behind your back... at least not without being told. Thread safety is a huge topic and this is just a footnote.

Comment: @J... The first two promises are similar. They look reasonable but how on earth could they be otherwise, are they a truism -- how could a function access anything that's not reachable via its argument? As for the third, is it saying for example I can have one thread iterating elements of any standard container while another thread inserts new elements?

Comment: @ChrisW _"... how could a function access anything that's not reachable via its argument..."_ a global or local static - some of the locale functions break this

Comment: @ChrisW _"...can have one thread iterating elements of any standard container while another thread inserts new elements..."_ no - each thread can access any element of the container independently.  Modifying the whole container is not accessing an element.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, I guess "static variables in the implementation of the library" may explain (or be at least one example of) the first two rules.

Answer (score 2):

OK I think I figured it out from the comments (please correct me if I'm wrong).

- These first two are similar -- i.e. that a function will only read or write memory that's reachable via the function argument.

  Perhaps this means, no more and no less than, that functions won't read or mutate global or static data in their implementation.

  There were a few functions in the C library which broke this rule, for example [ctime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime).

  > ctime returns a pointer to static data and is not thread-safe.
- The third is saying that a thread can mutate an element in a container while another thread accesses a different element.

  This does not imply that it's also inherently safe to mutate the container, e.g. to insert a new element.

  And [`vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is an exception to this rule:

  > `std::vector<bool>` behaves similarly to `std::vector`, but in order to be space efficient, it ... does not guarantee that different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads.

Comment: re (3) see my comment about `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: That makes sense, that it is an exception, knowing that `vector<bool>`  may be several bits per byte. Its not implementing a lock is an example of C++ not allowing the hobgoblin of consistency to interfere with naked (pedal to the metal) speed/simplicity.